Balancing Time and Switching Costs in a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP)
In many real-world Vehicle Routing Problems (VRP), there are additional complexities beyond minimizing total travel distance or time. One such complexity arises when there are switching costs incurred when transitioning between vehicles or routes. These switching costs might represent operational inefficiencies, reloading costs, or any other penalty associated with changing vehicles.
I am exploring ways to incorporate switching costs into the objective function of a VRP. The goal is to strike a balance between minimizing travel time and these additional costs. However, I am unsure how to design an objective function that appropriately weights these competing factors.

What approaches are commonly used to handle such trade-offs in VRPs?
Are there specific methods to determine the weight or scaling factors for switching costs relative to travel time?

